# Scrape many products with the same name Html. I can only scrape one, not all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have successfully performed a little scraping from a site through Selenium. The data downloaded without problems. Good! On the site there are many products that, in Html, have the same identical name.

At the moment, only a single product and its details (name, description, price, seller, etc.) have been scraped, but I would like to scrape ALL the products on the page .... which I repeat, they have the same same identical name. Here are the names:

```
#Selenium code for scraping        
Product_Name = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("tablet-desktop-only"). Text)
Product_Description = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("h-text-left"). Text)
Vendor = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("in-vendor"). Text)
Price = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("h-text-center"). Text)

print(Product_Name)
print(Product_Description)
print(Vendor)
print(Price)
```

How to scrape other products too if they have the same exact same name? I would like to create a list of all products, not just one product. Thank you

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the URL of the website you are trying to scrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to find all elements for each of the kinds of things you are looking for. So, start with:

```
Product_Names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tablet-desktop-only")
Product_Descriptions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("h-text-left")
Vendors = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("in-vendor")
Prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("h-text-center")
```

You should have 4 lists of elements (not strings), each of which should be the same length, and picking up things in the same order. To be safe we will choose to work with the shortest list.

```
Num_Groups = min(len(Product_Names),len(Product_Descriptions),len(Vendors), len(Prices))
```

Then we loop over all 4 lists at the same time:

```
for i in range(Num_Groups):
    print(Product_Names[i].text)
    print(Product_Descriptions[i].text)
    print(Vendors[i].text)
    print(Prices[i].text)
    #you might want to add printing a blank line here
```

Note we need `.text` here so we get the text of the element, not a description of the element itself. Also note the [i] to get that element in the list.

Within this loop is where you would do your database inserts (though probably connect outside the loop), making sure to merge the `.text` into the SQL string, not the element's string representation.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are very kind. Excuse me if I have created a bit of confusion with the various similar questions. Due to the time zone, it is very late clock here. Late tonight I will carefully read your kind answers. Then I will rate all of your answers in the various questions and close the questions. See you tonight. Thanks again :)

Comment: @FrederickMan don't upvote too many answers at the same time. No more than 3 upvotes, otherwise the site will automatically remove those upvotes.

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan Ok with Num_Groups and with for i in range (Num_Groups) you print the line you want in the Python console. Printing is precise and grouped. Now how can I go about printing all other lines (in the Python console) the same? That is, other data with the same name in the same way? That is, apply this code to all other identical html names? hat is, to print all the other remaining ones (Num_Groups)? Thank you

Comment: See a detailed answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68108984/python-save-the-previously-scraped-data-in-database-already-created/68109616?noredirect=1#comment120429523_68109616. What you describe suggests your Num_Groups is 1, which means your find_elements on at least one of those locators is matching only 1 item, not many. I added code to print the number of groups, so you will know.

Answer (score 1):

To find multiple elements with a specific class, we can use `find_elements_by_class_name` **(The difference with the function you wrote is that in this function you should write element, instead of elements!)**. This function returns a list from which we can select the desired element from its indexes.
Note that this gives you a list and you can not use text on it, but you must use it on its indexes.
Example :

```py
elements = find_elements_by_class_name('tablet-desktop-only')
print( elements[0].text )
# Or using a for :
for element in elements:
 print(element.text)
```

Comment: I tried adding "s" to element. I find an error. Scraping does not start. The error is as follows:
Product_Name = (driver.find_elements_by_class_name ("tablet-desktop-only"). Text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @FrederickMan : yes you need to use like I have shown above, a list in python does not have a text method. text is applicable for a single web element

Comment: Here it is late at night. I read better tomorrow. I go to sleep. Tomorrow I will read more carefully and vote the answers. Thank you. See you tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Just for an example if `tablet-desktop-only` represent multiple value for Product name. You should use `find_elements` not `find_element`

```
name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name ("tablet-desktop-only")
for nme in name:
    print(nme.text)
```

You can easily replicate this for others like `Description` , `Vendor` and `Price`

**Update 1 :**

above `name` is a list in Python, similarly you can have list for `Description` , `Vendor` and `Price`

Now we have 4 list, we can print items one by one like this :

```
for seq in name + Description + Vendor + Price:
    print(seq)
```

Comment: What is "for nme in name" for? Why write it? Thank you

Comment: that's a loop, when we use `find_elements` it returns a list. so I am iterating the list and then trying to print the text in each iteration.

Comment: Good, all right. Functiona! :) But the print is confusing, for example, like this: -Product_Name - Product_Name - Product_Name - Product_Name - Product_Description - Product_Description - Product_Description - Product_Description - Vendor - Vendor - Vendor - Vendor - Price - Price - Price - Price. How can I group the data in the same line (or vertically but in an organized way) in the following order: -Product_Name, Product_Description, -Vendor, -Price? That is, that each product visibly corresponds, Product_Description, -Vendor, -Price. Thank you

Comment: Check out the updated code under update 1 section. I hope that will resolve your issue

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: can you check my answer above, you would see Update 1 : in bold.. that's is how you should print them in sequence

Comment: Aaaaa, ok, I did not see. Thank you. Here it is late at night. I read better tomorrow. I go to sleep. Tomorrow I will read more carefully and vote the answers. Thank you. See you tomorrow

Comment: The situation has improved a lot. Thank you. But there is still something wrong. I would simply like to print with the following order: Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price .... Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price .... Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price. (I continue in another comment, because it is too long)

Comment: Currently, however, with your kind suggestion, only Product_Name, Product_Description are printed in a grouped way, while Vendor and Price are printed at the end. Let me explain with an example: Product_Name, Product_Description .... Product_Name, Product_Description .... Product_Name, Product_Description .... Vendor, Vendor, Vendor, Price, Price, Price. How can I solve? Thank you