# Python: Save the previously scraped data in database (already created)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have done the scraping with Selenium correctly and the results are printed perfectly. I don't know how to save them in a database I have already created the tables and fields with Sqlite. In general I know how to save the data in a database, but I don't know how to save the scraping data. What I don't know is how to write the code to save the scraping data.

Now I would just like to add the scraped data into the database and save. The database table name is TableExample1. The fields are: ID, Product_NameDB, Product_DescriptionDB, VendorDB, PriceDB.

I have 2 problems

1. The text that is saved in the database like this: [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session = "226bc9f3
2. Only one (1) row is added to the database. Instead, dozens or hundreds of them should be added (each like this: Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price), depending on the scraped data.

The Python code with the data printed by the scraping is as follows:

```
#Name of the scraped data 
Product_Name = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("tablet-desktop-only"). Text)
Product_Description = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("h-text-left"). Text)
Vendor = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("in-vendor"). Text)
Price = (driver.find_element_by_class_name ("h-text-center"). Text)

for seq in Product_Name + Product_Description + Vendor + Price:
    print(seq.text)
```

**UPDATE N.1
Current code, following ["Jeremy Kahan"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6656050/jeremy-kahan)'s answers to this question**
and in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68093571/scrape-many-products-with-the-same-name-html-i-can-only-scrape-one-not-all-of) (it is different, I asked to print in the console all the results of the scraping and not just 1)

This is the current most stable and functioning code. Scraping works fine, but that Num_Groups and for i in range (Num_Groups) you suggested in the other question, print only one group, not all.

I still have the same 2 problems

1. The text that is saved in the database like this: [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session = "226bc9f3
2. Only one (1) row is added to the database. Instead, dozens or hundreds of them should be added (each like this: Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price), depending on the scraped data.

   ```
    import sqlite3
    from datetime import datetime 

    #SCRAPING
    Product_Name=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tablet-desktop-only")
    Product_Description=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("h-text-left")
    Vendor=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("in-match")
    Price=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("h-text-center")


    # How do I print the other data always with the same html name?
    # This is one row data. This is the code you wrote me in the  
    # other question. Print only one group. What to write to print 
    # all groups?  
    Num_Groups = min(len(Product_Name),len(Product_Description),len(Vendor), len(Price))

    for i in range(Num_Groups):    
        print(Product_Name[i].text)
        print(Product_Description[i].text)
        print(Vendor[i].text)
        print(Price[i].text)


    #INSERT DATA IN DATABASE
    con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Desktop/aaaaa/Database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()

    ID=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    Values =   f"VALUES({ID},'{Product_Name}','{Product_Description}','{Vendor}','{Price}')"
    sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO TableExample1 (ID, Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price)' + Values

    count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
    con.commit()
    print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
    cursor.close()
   ```

**2° UPLOAD (final?)**
PROBLEM: found 12 groups, Record inserted successfully 1, Added a total of 1 records How do I get 12 staves inserted in the database?

```
Num_Groups = min(len(Product_Name),len(Product_Description),len(Vendor), len(Price))

records_added = 0

 for i in range(Num_Groups):    
     print(Product_Name[i].text)
     print(Product_Description[i].text)
     print(Vendor[i].text)
     print(Price[i].text)


con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/aaaa/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

Values = f" VALUES ('{Product_Name[i].text}','{Product_Description[i].text}','{Vendor[i].text}','{Price[i].text}')"
sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price)' + Values

print("Qui, all'interno del ciclo, eseguiresti" + sqlite_insert_query)

count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
con.commit()
print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
records_added = records_added + 1
cursor.close()

print("")
print(f'Added a total of {records_added} records')
print(f"found {Num_Groups} groups")  # should be more than 1
```

Comment: https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-insert-into-table/ and maybe try an f-string as at https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thank you so much for your kind reply. I'm just starting out with Python though. Could you please show me the code I should use for my question case? I ask you please. I really ask you with my heart. In my question there are only 4 data and I have provided all the details of the database. Thanks and sorry. I will vote for you as the best answer

Comment: @JeremyKahan ADD: In general I know how to save the data in a database, but I don't know how to save the scraping data. In your link you show me how to use the database: I already know. What I don't know is how to write the code to save the scraping data.

Comment: If Product_Name is already gotten with .Text (you have an extra space between the dot and text), it's a string and seq.text below fails. My answer assumes Product_Name is a string, not an element. If that's not true, where I wrote Product_Name, you will need Product_Name.Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So you are telling me you are good with connecting to the database, getting a cursor, executing sql with the cursor and the connection, and committing changes and closing the cursor. What you need is the sql string to execute.

```
Values = f"VALUES('{Product_Name}','{Product_Description}','{Vendor}','{Price}')"
sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO TableExample1(Product_NameDB, Product_DescriptionDB, VendorDB, PriceDB) ' + Values
```

Then you should be able to, assuming `cursor` is the cursor set up:

```
count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
```

I am assuming you set things up so ID is a unique key that will be generated if you do not specify it.

EDIT: So it sounds like the database was struggling with the ID and not making more than one new one. Assuming your IDs just need to be sequential (and only you are using it and scraping takes more than a second), you could handle IDs yourself as follows. After `from datetime import datetime` earlier

```
ID=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
Values = f"VALUES({ID},'{Product_Name}','{Product_Description}','{Vendor}','{Price}')"
sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO TableExample1(ID, Product_NameDB, Product_DescriptionDB, VendorDB, PriceDB) ' + Values
```

Also, you mentioned getting the text describing the element in Product_Name as opposed to just the Product_Name (and similarly for the other fields). You need:

```
Product_Name = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tablet-desktop-only").text
```

(or to put `(Product_Name.text)` in my f-string, but that seems confusing)

**2ND Edit:**
What @Prophet was trying to say at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110293/problems-saving-scraped-data-to-database-python/68111109?noredirect=1#comment120399103_68111109 is as follows.
When you say:

```
`Product_Name = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tablet-desktop-only").text`
```

`Product_Name` is a string, and your for loop on `Product_Name + Product_Description + Vendor + Price`
is looping over a single concatenated string, and seq then has the characters of the string, taken one at a time. Then `seq.text` fails, as you experienced. That is why I commented out the `print` command over there, and put one in later to print the `Values` string instead. That is an approach that should work.

If you leave things the way you had them originally

```
`Product_Name = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tablet-desktop-only")
```

Product_Name is an element, which when merged into the Values string, gets converted to a string representation of the element, which is why you see all that irrelevant text in the database. I understand your leaving it so that the for loop will work, but then you should do something like this:

```
ID=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
Values = f"VALUES({ID},'{Product_Name.text}','{Product_Description.text}','{Vendor.text}','{Price.text}')"
```

or

```
Product_Name_Text = Product_Name.Text
Product_Description_Text = Product_Description.Text
Vendor_Text = Vendor.Text
Price_Text = Price.Text
```

and then

```
Values = f"VALUES({ID},'{Product_Name_Text}','{Product_Description_Text}','{Vendor_Text}','{Price_Text}')"
```

or

```
ID=datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
Values = f"VALUES({ID}"

for seq in Product_Name + Product_Description + Vendor + Price:
    print(seq.text)
    Values = Values + "," + "'" + seq.text + "'"
Values = Values + ")"
```

I would definitely recommend, at least for debugging, printing `Values` or `sqlite_insert_query`. If you share those results back with us, we may be able to help, if it's still not working.

In the above options you can leave out my assigning the ID if that turns out not be an issue after all.

I do not see any loop in your code over different groups of elements, so I am not sure what you are expecting in terms of inserting more than one new entry.

**3rd (final?) Edit:**
There are 2 issues you are having. That you are getting extra stuff in the database is because you are putting the description of each element into the Values part of the SQL as opposed to the text. I have illustrated how to fix that by formmating the text into the Values string.
The second issue you are having is that your locator is finding only one thing when you say find_elements (I cannot debug your locators because I don't know the page). But the code here should tell you how many things matched. To test that hypothesis, I wrote my own version below, that works (if the page is permanent) grabbing data from Amazon on cosmetics. The details are not important, but the code should illustrate what has to happen. Also, I believe what I did earlier with IDs in unnecessary, the database will handle that.
Since I am not actually a database, I commented that out. You will uncomment it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# launch and go to site, yours will vary
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/b?node=18505451011&pd_rd_w=gVvMZ&pf_rd_p=b6363b44-58dd-4354-979f-1446a1c45f7a&pf_rd_r=5FYAS41AJR7GPQ5Q74J4&pd_rd_r=9bfd1639-2256-4c17-928c-99cf03e00d63&pd_rd_wg=UPUHV")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "See all results")))

# SCRAPING
# you will want to change back to your locators
Product_Name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("apb-line-clamp-3")
# actually number of reviewers, picks up see all at the bottom, too, but it's ok because of min
Product_Description = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-color-link")
Vendor = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "apb-browse-searchresults-product-byline")
Price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-price")  # prices

# if the locators work well, these match multiple groups of products not just one
Num_Groups = min(len(Product_Name), len(
    Product_Description), len(Vendor), len(Price))
print(f"found {Num_Groups} groups")  # should be more than 1

# I have commented out the database code, because I am not actually using one
#con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Desktop/aaaaa/Database.db')
# connect to database outside the loop, not for each item
# I removed the code about generating ID's, which the database should handle
records_added = 0
for i in range(Num_Groups):  # should cause i to count from 0 up to and including Num_Groups-1
    print("")  # skip a line between stuff
    print(Product_Name[i].text)
    print(Product_Description[i].text)
    print(Vendor[i].text)
    print(Price[i].text)
    # note below I need to format the .text into the values string, not the text description of the element
    Values = f" VALUES ('{Product_Name[i].text}','{Product_Description[i].text}','{Vendor[i].text}','{Price[i].text}')"
    sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price)' + Values
    print("Here, inside the loop,  you would execute " + sqlite_insert_query)
    #cursor = con.cursor()
    #count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
    # con.commit()
    #print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
    records_added = records_added + 1
    # cursor.close()
print("")
print(f'Added a total of {records_added} records')
```

output was:

```
found 12 groups

Crest 3D White Professional Effects Whitestrips 20 Treatments + Crest 3D White 1 Hour Express Whitestrips 2 Treatments - Teeth Whitening Kit
46,020
by Crest
$47
88
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Crest 3D White Professional Effects Whitestrips 20 Treatments + Crest 3D White 1 Hour Express Whitestrips 2 Treatments - Teeth Whitening Kit','46,020','by Crest','$47
88')

REVLON One-Step Hair Dryer And Volumizer Hot Air Brush, Black, Packaging May Vary
274,196
by REVLON
$41
99
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('REVLON One-Step Hair Dryer And Volumizer Hot Air Brush, Black, Packaging May Vary','274,196','by REVLON','$41
99')

Waterpik WP-660 Water Flosser Electric Dental Countertop Professional Oral Irrigator For Teeth, Aquarius, White
72,786
by Waterpik
$59.99
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Waterpik WP-660 Water Flosser Electric Dental Countertop Professional Oral Irrigator For Teeth, Aquarius, White','72,786','by Waterpik','$59.99')

Schick Hydro Silk Touch-Up Multipurpose Exfoliating Dermaplaning Tool, Eyebrow Razor, and Facial Razor with Precision Cover, 3 Count (Packaging May Vary)
113,269
by Schick Hydro Silk
$68
27
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Schick Hydro Silk Touch-Up Multipurpose Exfoliating Dermaplaning Tool, Eyebrow Razor, and Facial Razor with Precision Cover, 3 Count (Packaging May Vary)','113,269','by Schick Hydro Silk','$68
27')

Neutrogena Makeup Remover Cleansing Face Wipes, Daily Cleansing Facial Towelettes to Remove Waterproof Makeup and Mascara, Alcohol-Free, Value Twin Pack, 25 Count, 2 Pack
62,881
by Neutrogena
$4
99
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Neutrogena Makeup Remover Cleansing Face Wipes, Daily Cleansing Facial Towelettes to Remove Waterproof Makeup and Mascara, Alcohol-Free, Value Twin Pack, 25 Count, 2 Pack','62,881','by Neutrogena','$4
99')

Gillette Fusion Power Men's Razor Blades - 8 Refills
32,435
by Gillette
$6.99
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Gillette Fusion Power Men's Razor Blades - 8 Refills','32,435','by Gillette','$6.99')

Softsoap Moisturizing Liquid Hand Soap, Soothing Clean Aloe Vera - 7.5 Fluid Ounces (6 Pack)
47,238
by Softsoap
$8
12
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Softsoap Moisturizing Liquid Hand Soap, Soothing Clean Aloe Vera - 7.5 Fluid Ounces (6 Pack)','47,238','by Softsoap','$8
12')

Neutrogena Lightweight Body Oil for Dry Skin, Sheer Body Moisturizer in Light Sesame Formula, 16 fl. oz
13,011
by Neutrogena
$11.96
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Neutrogena Lightweight Body Oil for Dry Skin, Sheer Body Moisturizer in Light Sesame Formula, 16 fl. oz','13,011','by Neutrogena','$11.96')

Crest 3D White Whitestrips with Light, Teeth Whitening Strips Kit, 10 Treatments, 20 Individual Strips (Packaging May Vary)
9,172
by Crest
$23
91
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Crest 3D White Whitestrips with Light, Teeth Whitening Strips Kit, 10 Treatments, 20 Individual Strips (Packaging May Vary)','9,172','by Crest','$23
91')

Neutrogena Hydro Boost Hyaluronic Acid Hydrating Water Gel Daily Face Moisturizer for Dry Skin, Oil-Free, Non-Comedogenic Face Lotion, 1.7 fl. oz
51,417
by Neutrogena
$32.51
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Neutrogena Hydro Boost Hyaluronic Acid Hydrating Water Gel Daily Face Moisturizer for Dry Skin, Oil-Free, Non-Comedogenic Face Lotion, 1.7 fl. oz','51,417','by Neutrogena','$32.51')

CHI 44 Iron Guard Thermal Protection Spray 8 Fl Oz
17,660
by CHI
$5
33
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('CHI 44 Iron Guard Thermal Protection Spray 8 Fl Oz','17,660','by CHI','$5
33')

Crest 3D White Toothpaste Radiant Mint (3 Count of 4.1 oz Tubes), 12.3 oz (Packaging May Vary)
40,354
by Crest
$13.99
Here, inside the loop,  you would execute INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price) VALUES ('Crest 3D White Toothpaste Radiant Mint (3 Count of 4.1 oz Tubes), 12.3 oz (Packaging May Vary)','40,354','by Crest','$13.99')

added a total of 12 records
```

**REVISION**
Here is what your code needs to look like.

```
Num_Groups = min(len(Product_Name),len(Product_Description),len(Vendor), len(Price))
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/aaaa/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
records_added = 0

for i in range(Num_Groups):    
     print(Product_Name[i].text)
     print(Product_Description[i].text)
     print(Vendor[i].text)
     print(Price[i].text)
     Values = f" VALUES ('{Product_Name[i].text}','{Product_Description[i].text}','{Vendor[i].text}','{Price[i].text}')"
     sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_Name, Product_Description, Vendor, Price)' + Values
     print("Qui, all'interno del ciclo, eseguiresti" + sqlite_insert_query)
     count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
     con.commit()
     print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
     records_added = records_added + 1
cursor.close()
```

The body of code indented under the `for:` is executed for each value of i (in the case you mentioned, from 0 to 11). Right now, because your database insert is outside this loop, it is only executed once.

**Really the last edit:**
We will use a parameterized query to let the database engine handle the apostrophe in the values (and anything else I may have missed). From what I am reading, that is a safer approach anyway to help prevent SQL injection attacks.

Change the `Values=` line (keeping the same indentation) to

```
Values = (Product_Name[i].text, Product_Description[i].text, Vendor[i].text, Price[i].text)
```

Change the `sqlite_insert_query =` line to say (keeping the same indentation as now):

```
sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO TableExample1 (Product_NameDB, Product_DescriptionDB, VendorDB, PriceDB) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);'
```

change the `count=cursor.execute` line to say

```
count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, Values)
```

That should work better and be safer. If it works, there is some optional cleaning up you could do. For example you could set sqlite_insert_query outside the loop, back where you connect to the database and initialize variables. You could also stop printing sqlite_insert_query and print Values instead (or just not print any of it since you have the 4 lines earlier that print the values).

Comment: Thanks so much. Strangely, however, I find an error. Only a new ID (only 1) is added to the database. I would like to add many. The ID is set as unique, but only a new one is generated. Also in the database there is some strange text (I uploaded the screenshot to imgbb): https://ibb.co/zxQ27BC. How can I solve the two? Thank you

Comment: I have modified the python code with all your kind suggestions.  now I get this error as soon as scraping starts: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'". Before, however, with my code, scraping worked. What didn't work was inserting into the database. Why? How to solve? Thank you

Comment: I have removed all the .text and the scraping text prints well and legible. I have left .text only in print (seq.text). By doing this, everything is fine, but the data still does NOT save in the database. As mentioned, one (1) only new staff with ID is added to each scraping attempt .... and not as many staves as there are data. Also inside the stave fields, this [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session = "226bc9f3-ea is always printed. So your answers are very kind, but they are not helping me Can you better review the cod please? Thanks

Comment: By the way, you won't need my handling of the ID explicitly as here. The database can generate them for you. You just need to call on it more than once, setting up the query fresh for each product, inside the for loop posed in the other question you asked.

Comment: All your kind answers (much appreciated, thanks), but they are confusing me. I've tried your different suggestions a bit, but there is something wrong. I do not know what to do. And I still have those 2 problems. I've updated the question. If you go up on the page, I have added "UPDATE" to it. I wrote the code I currently use and it seems more stable and working. With your numerous responses in this post and the other, I have written several types of code and am very confused. Thank you. We hope to resolve, my head blows and I'm losing hope. Yet it is a simple thing

Comment: if performance becomes an issue, or maybe for good style anyway, once everything else is working, you may want to try taking getting and closing the cursor such that one is before the loop after connecting, and the other is after the loop. Same goes for the commit.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. In your previous answers, you did not write to me that I had to add [i] IN VALUES. If I first write the code {Product_Name.text}', it didn't work: error. You didn't write {Product_Name [i] .text} with [i]: now it's ok, the text is saved normally and clearly in the database. Problem solved. But there is still another problem. In the database you enter only one (1) ID, and not 12 (for example). For example, I am written like this: found 12 groups, Record inserted successfully 1, Added a total of 1 records How do I get 12 staves inserted in the database?Thanks

Comment: Do you have the cursor.execute indented inside the for loop like I do?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I have published the current version by modifying the question with 2° UPLOAD (FINAL?). cursor.execute I used it like this. What do i need to change? Can you show me a code example? If you answer in a comment, maybe I don't understand. I do not speak English very well. Thank you. You are really kind :)

Comment: See the revision I just posted. You need to make sure the insert command is built and executed for each group found, which means it has to be in the block indented under the for statement

Comment: I did the same as you suggested. Thanks. There is still a small problem. Scraping starts in the console, then an error is printed: count = cursor.execute (sqlite_insert_query) slite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error. I checked the database and only 6 products are entered (not 12) which are: Only six products (Crest 3D, Revlon, Waterpik, Schick, Neitrogena, Chi Silk. I noticed that if I move count = cursor.execute (sqlite_insert_query) and with .commit () I don't have the above error, but I am seeing others. We are nearing the final solution. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: I do not think it is worth your trying to fix my messing around on Amazon. I thought you would redo with your own site and data and locators. The problem is probably the carriage return in the middle of one of my prices or something. If you look at the printed query right before it messes up, you will probably see the issue. I don't think it's worth worrying about errors in data I grabbed, Probably first see how it goes with the data you actually want.

Comment: In fact, it's not worth fixing the mess with Amazon. Amazon is for example only. I thought the problem was in the code,regardless of whether you use Amazon or other sites. Before the error,I get this: Gillette Fusion Power Men's Razor Blades - 8 Refills 32,437 by Gillette $ 6.99 Here, within the cycle, you would run INSERT INTO etc etc...) VALUES ('Gillette Fusion Men's Power Razor Blades - 8 Refills', '32,437', 'by Gillette', '$ 6.99').Are you sure it's not a code problem?I believe that even the site and links change, the error comes out anyway.What should I change to the code?

Comment: So it does have an error when run on the site you are interested in? I am betting the problem is the apostrophe in "Men's", which it thinks is closing the Values string. Let me think about how to fix that.

Comment: See latest revision at the very bottom indicating changes to the query (parameterized and constant), the Values (now a tuple), and the execute (now taking two arguments). These address the apostrophe (which was causing the error) and security.

Comment: Perfect. You solved. You are the best, both humanly and intellectually. Thank you. Can the code you suggested to me scrape from any site? (excluding proxy and blocking issues). I'm having problems, only 2 groups are printed and not all of them. The problem is the code or am I wrong to fetch the html? Did I write the name of the 4 red data correctly that I would like to scrape? This is the photo https://ibb.co/GJhXwDM and this is the link https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/sweden/allsvenskan/results/ Thanks and sorry

Comment: So the code was assuming that you were looking at things that came with 4 parts appearing for each item. The page you were looking at has only two tablet-desktop-only items, and the second one you don't even want. So you want to do a find_element (not elements) on that one, not include it in calculating the numbers of groups, and put the variable without the [i] but with the .text into the 4-tuple of values.

Comment: I did not understand very well. Never mind. Just stop it here. You solved my question problem. I thank you so much. You are a really good person. Thank you. I really appreciated your kindness and your patience. If you like, I have raised this problem again in the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68177247/selenium-problems-in-grouping-of-print I have rated your answers in this and the other question. Thanks so much again